# How to delete HttpCookie object value in class file

Tags: c#

when I assign a cookie like below

```
string sKey = txtUName.Text + txtPwd.Text;
HttpCookie uidpwd = new HttpCookie("uidpwd");
 uidpwd.Value = sKey;
Response.Cookies.Add(uidpwd);
```

so want to delete it in class file like below

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["uidpwd"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(1);
```

but throwing an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: I'm guessing in the second piece of code you either don't have access to the Current HttpContext object (unlikely) or that the Request cookies collection doesn't contain the cookie you are trying to amend.

Comment: can you provide a bit more context, say, when exactly are you adding the cookie and when are you trying to delete it? generally you should first check for the cookie to be present.
Also you should probably set the Expires property to DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1) to explicitly mark it as already expired

Comment: You need to explain your flow. As in first code path , you are adding cookie to Response object. So in request it will be available in Postback.

Answer (score 1):

`Request` is collection of incoming stuff, what you're looking for is `Response`. When browser sends you a cookie, .NET framework translates that to `Request.Cookies` property; and for application scenario you can think about this collection as read-only collection. When you want to set a cookie; you have to add it to `Response.Cookies` collection.

So the expiration should look like:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(
  new HttpCookie("uidpwd") { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) }
);
```